# Is there a function to round p values?

Tags: r

In `glm`, `lm` and others function in [r](/questions/tagged/r) which produced pvalues, there are kindly printed. For example :

```
p found   | p printed
--------- | -----
0.000032  | <0.001 ***
0.012322  |  0.012 **
0.233432  |  0.233
```

There must be a built-in function to produce this but I didn't achieve to find it. I search in the R documentation, Google and in SO without success. For the moment I use a hand-made function but I have to copy-paste it and call it each time I perform an analysis where I want to produce nice pvalue to output tables.

Comment: Have a look at `printCoefmat`

Comment: What is the issue here? Having 1.23456 printed as 1.23 or having the stars next to the coefficients?

Comment: @James Thank's! I founded in the `printCoefmat` documentation the function `format.pval` wich help. It's not perfectly what I want but It's not to far. @nico I will edit my question to be more explicit about the issue

Comment: After some test and reading also the `format` documentation, `format.pval` act exactly as I want. For example : `format.pval(c(0.99, 0.2, 0.32312, 0.0000123213, 0.002), 2, 0.001, nsmall = 3)` give as expected `"0.990"  "0.200"  "0.323"  "<0.001" "0.002"`. Thank's again. @nico The issue was to have both 1.23456 printed as 1.23.

Comment: @James @jomuller +1 for `format.pval`, I usually use a cobbled-together function of my own to print p-values but this is much more handy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*I answer my own question thank's to @James comments.*)

Use `format.pval` with the right arguments. `digits` and `eps` are the most important.

Example :

```
pvalues <- c(0.99, 0.2, 0.32312, 0.0000123213, 0.002)

format.pval(pv = pvalues, 

             # digits : number of digits, but after the 0.0
            digits = 2, 

             # eps = the threshold value above wich the 
             # function will replace the pvalue by "<0.0xxx"
            eps = 0.001, 

             # nsmall = how much tails 0 to keep if digits of 
             # original value < to digits defined
            nsmall = 3
            )

# "0.990" "0.200" "0.323" "<0.001" "0.002"
```

`format.pval` return a character vector.

To have the stars just use `ifelse` or write a function

```
ifelse(pvalues < 0.05, "*", "")
```